# Multiple switches enable all at once when generated from array react-native

Tags: react-native, switch-statement, toggle

What would you do to just enable the one switch (toggle) the user wishes to enable?

Here is my state:

```
state = {
  menuItems: [
    { title: 'Test1', switchValue: false },
    { title: 'Test2', switchValue: false }
]};
```

Here is my constructor:

```
constructor(props: any) {
super(props);
this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
```

}

And here is function control toggle:

```
toggle(item: any) {
  const menu = [...this.state.menuItems];
  menu[item].switchValue = !menu[item].switchValue;

  this.setState({ menu });
}
```

And here is the map look like that:

```
public render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    {this.state.menuItems.map((item, index) => (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.showSettingHint} key={item.title}>
        <View style={[styles.rowContainer, index === 0 ? styles.topRowContainer : null]}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
          <Switch
            onValueChange={this.toggle}
            value={item.switchValue}
          />
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ))}
  </View>
);}
```

But I got an error like this:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'menu[item].switchValue')

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the toggle function expects an index for the menu item as an argument.

```
toggle(item: any) {
  const menu = [...this.state.menuItems];
  menu[item].switchValue = !menu[item].switchValue;

  this.setState({ menu });
}
```

And in your Switch you are not passing the index of the menu item then, I think it would work if you pass the index in the onValueChange like so:

```
      <Switch
        //Add index here
        onValueChange={this.toggle(index)}
        value={item.switchValue}
      />
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I just mixed your answer with mine and it not work.

Comment: btw I changed menuItems from state to array and it works!!